# Need to get all values from Org. I had updated the API version of apex class to 51.0. While getting the value from Org I doesn't able to get

Tags: apex

Milestone1_Settings__c settings = Milestone1_Settings__c.getOrgdefaults();

Hi Someone help me to clear this error. I had updated the API version of Apex class from version 22.0 to 51.0.After Updating, the method GetorgDefaults() was not working. If there is any other alternate ways to fetch all the data from Org.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing to do is always check the developer documentation and look at the methods available for custom settings.

A quick Google search reveals this help page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

Assuming that it's a list custom setting, getAll() method is probably what you're looking for. Though I suggest walking through the full documentation page to make sure.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas I also tried using getAll() method Its showing an error "Attempt to de-reference a Null Object"  Its there is any other solutions?

Comment: Can you provide the larger context? What is this Milestone1_Settings__c? Is it indeed a custom setting? And what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Milestone_settings__c is custom Object as well as it is an custom settings and I had tried out the (setAllData = true) and code coverage is increased. Is that is correct solution? @Nicolas

Comment: @Mickey01 There are a couple of items to tackle. First, were you able to resolve the Null Pointer? Second, (seeAllData=true) should never be used. It indicates that you aren't properly creating your test data. Make sure to create records for the milestone settings in your test setup. Finally, you're suddenly talking about test coverage? Is your problem really the API version change or are you struggling with test coverage?

Comment: Due to API version changes only I got this error. If there is any other possible  ways to get all data from Org instead of using getOrgdefault().@Nicolas

Comment: @Mickey01 I've done some further research and found this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092kvIAA
Conclusion: seems like you're not inserting the Custom Settings in your test class. You should always create your test data first.